# Action of group of order $(p-1)p$ on a $\mathbb F_p$ vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

By classification, I find that any group of order $42$ cannot act on a finite dimensional $\mathbb F_7$ vector space $V$ such the representation is irreducible and faithful. Does it hold generally? Assume a group of order $(p-1)p$ on a $\mathbb F_p$ vector space $V$, could the representation be both irreducible and faithful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any group of order $(p-1)p$ has a normal subgroup of order $p$ by Sylow's Theorem.

In general, if $N$ is a normal $p$-subgroup of any finite group  $G$, then $N$ is in the kernel of any irreducible representation of $G$ over a field with characteristic $p$. (This is because the only irreducible represenation of $N$ in characteristic $p$ is the trivial one, so $N$ must have fixed points in its action on the $G$-module, and hence it must act trivially by irreducibility of the $G$-module.) So if $1 \ne N$, then $G$ has no faithful irreducible representation over a field with characteristic $p$.

So the answer to your question is no.